# Evaporative emission system purge control valve circuit

Tags: ford, fiesta, evap

I just use my scan tool on my 2015 ford fiesta and this what came up. What does this mean and can I fix the problem. Code:P0443

Answer (score 0):

P0443 is a generic code which is saying the ECU has detected a malfunction with the purge control valve or its control circuit. If you manually told the purge control valve to cycle, the ECU could have seen this as an issue and popped the code. Clear the code and see if it comes back. You won't know for sure until the drive cycle has finished as the EVAP system is one of those things which gets checked.

Comment: I deleted code and drove it around and the code still comes up

Comment: Since I swap back to my original ECM and didn't start so I put the ECM that installed, car start drive ok I guess but more codes appears when I scan my car. I have left low beam light turning on then turning off. It looks like everything is not communicate with the ECM since I removed it and place it back into my car. This car is a good car but sense like when I fix one thing something else pops up.

Comment: Check your battery voltage. A low battery can cause sporadic/random electrical issues which.